# Using ngSanitize want to add jQuery onClick() with Angular data binding code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created some search functionality with Angular js.

showing the HTML content using **ngSanitize**. Now in the HTML data I want to use jQuery onClick().

I tried a lot but no luck something is wrong:

Below is the Angular controls' code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    get: function(callback){
      $http.get('assets/script/items.json').success(function(data){
        callback(data);
      })
    }
  }
}]);

myApp.factory('Categories', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    get: function(callback){
      $http.get('assets/script/categories.json').success(function(data){
        callback(data);
      })
    }
  }
}]);

// Config and Routes 
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl:"home.html"
        })
        .when('/item/:id', {
                templateUrl:"item.html"
        })
})

myApp.controller('headerController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.goHome = function () {
    $location.path('/');
  };
})



function controller($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}

// Controllers
myApp.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){

  Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response;
  });

  // Update this value dynamically - onclick
  $scope.filters = "food";

  $scope.viewDetail = function(item) {
        $location.path('/item/' + item.id);
    }

})  


myApp.controller('ListController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

  $scope.sendCategory = function(category) {
    // How can I pass this value to ItemController?
     $scope.search =category.name;
  };

   $scope.orderProp='title';

    $scope.tab = function (tabIndex) {
     //Sort by date
      if (tabIndex == 1){
        //alert(tabIndex);
        $scope.orderProp='date';

      }   
      //Sort by views 
      if (tabIndex == 2){
        $scope.orderProp = 'views';
      }

   };

   $scope.sort = function(item) {
       if (  $scope.orderProp == 'date') {
            return new Date(item.date);
        }
        return item[$scope.orderProp];
   }

})  


myApp.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

  Categories.get(function(response){
    $scope.categories = response;
  });


})  

myApp.controller("tabsController", function ($scope) {

   $scope.orderProp = 'date';

})

myApp.controller('ItemDetailController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){

    $scope.goHome = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };

    Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response; 

    if ($route.current.params.id) {
      angular.forEach($scope.items, function (v, k) {
        if (v.id == $route.current.params.id) {
          $scope.currItem = $scope.items[k];
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

jSon Data sample:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "My Title",
    "src": "assets/images/myPic.jpg",
    "description": "<p>Hello p tag</p><h2>heading</h2><div>Content</div>",
    "organization": "My Organization",
    "currentrole": "My Current Role"        
  },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "My Title",
    "src": "assets/images/myPic2.jpg",
    "description": "<p>Hello p tag 2</p><h2>heading2</h2><div>Content 2</div>",
    "organization": "My Organization",
    "currentrole": "My Current Role"        
  }
]
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use jquery for a click event, You can use Angular ng-click event to bind any html element to an angular $scope function. Look at the docs:

[Angular ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

You could also use standard javascript

```
var someelement = document.getElementById("myelement");

someelement .addEventListener("click",function(e){
   //Insert code
},false);
```

Comment: bcz creating some custom onClick() methods after binding the HTML via **ngSanitize**..

Comment: i still don't think you should use jquery just because you want a click event so i added the javascript equivalent @mufeedAhmad

Comment: but I am done with it.. for that I have included my required functions end of the $scop controller.. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the code what I meant:

```
myApp.controller('ItemDetailController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){

    $scope.goHome = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };

    Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response; 

    if ($route.current.params.id) {
      angular.forEach($scope.items, function (v, k) {
        if (v.id == $route.current.params.id) {
          $scope.currItem = $scope.items[k];
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('.detailed').on('click', 'h4', function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('activeHead');
    });
})
```